# Git does not reset the changes

Tags: git

```
Z:\>git reset --hard origin/master
HEAD is now at 26b3190 Additional PEGI descriptions

Z:\>git diff-files
:100644 100644 883b63ea7d16ae9825023d555a315308bd807cb5 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 M file1.php
:100644 100644 49e23a1fc547b773a0ca690d709b9504f20d16fa 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 M file2.php
```

After the reset has changed files. Many different methods have tried - do not solve the problem.

Comment: Please don't use screenshots, instead wrap the terminal output in backticks or something. That's impossible to read. It'll also save you from having to put in the effort of blurring things out. :)

Comment: would you mind copy-n-pasting the code you run? it's barely readable (and consists only of text anyhow)

Comment: Sorry, added the code

Comment: Give me a minute, I'm meant to be doing actual work over here ;)

Comment: Did you ever work this out?

Comment: @wdh only part of the problem

Comment: What's left to solve? Did you try to `git stash save`?

Comment: @wdh yes, I have tried. After `git stash save` display `You have unstaged changes` :( `git diff master origin/master` is empty, but `git diff-files` displayed everything that the earlier.

Comment: If the changes are unstaged, just `mv path/to/file path/to/outside/your/repo` them away.

Comment: @wdh it helped, but I think that the problem will come back soon

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40738/discussion-between-newpdv-and-wdh)

Answer (score 1):

Are those files new? Git will not touch files that haven't been committed yet but they will appear in the output of git diff-files. If so, it shouldn't be a problem at all. Either `git add path/to/file`each file and commit it or just `rm path/to/file` the files that you don't want to keep.

Edit:
From your comment below, you are trying to checkout master but you've forced all the files to be in the state that origin/master is in. origin/master is a separate branch and therefore it might have changes.

If you really want to checkout to master `git stash save` to move your changes somewhere safe, `git checkout master` to move branch and then `git stash pop` to bring your changed php files back (if you want them)

Comment: No. This is the old files.
Checkout does not work after reset.

`Z:\>git reset --hard origin/master
HEAD is now at 26b3190 Additional PEGI descriptions

Z:\>git checkout master
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
        file1.php
        file2.php
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches.
Aborting`

Comment: You are trying to checkout master but you've forced all the files to be in the state that origin/master is in. origin/master is a separate branch and therefore it might have changes. Do a `git diff master origin/master` to see exactly what the differences are. If afterward you want to checkout to master you can just `git stash save` to move your changes somewhere safe, `git checkout master` to move branch and then `git stash pop` to bring your changed php files back (if you want them)

Comment: i wrote: `git checkout master`, then `git stash save`, but `git pull` with resolve, after this displayed `Cannot pull with rebase: You have unstaged changes.`